# jquery autocomplete plugin IE 9 not working

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

If you go to:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

and try the example in IE 9, it does not work. Every other browser it does work. I have searched around the internet for a quick fix but can't seem to find one. It seems to be making the ajax request for the autocomplete, but NOT displaying the box.

Comment: You can always try the metatag:
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're not going to find an IE 9 fix for this.**  You should [read the author's page](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) for [your plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete).  It's been deprecated and the last version of Explorer it's been tested with is 7.

[http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/)

*"Note (2010-06-23): This plugin is deprecated and not developed anymore. Its [successor is part of jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/), and [this migration guide](http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide) explains how to get from this plugin to the new one. This page will remain as it is for reference, but won’t be updated anymore.*

*If you’re still using the plugin and can’t upgrade to jQuery UI autocomplete: [Someone else is maintaining a GitHub repository with the plugin, including some fixes](https://github.com/agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin).*

*There’s also an [update to the original version of the standalone plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-autocomplete/) in a Google Code project."*

Answer (score 5):

Actually the fix is quite easy. You just need to update one file. Sad that no one posted this before.

See here: http://hax.at/text/49

Answer (score 1):

I will just add my two cents even though the original question was long ago.

I hope this can help someone else that was having the same trouble I was.  I am using the jQuery UI's autocomplete and having trouble with IE9 as well.  I checked all the things mentioned in this thread... a few days ago, and then gave up for a few days to work on something else.  As I revisited it today I came across this: [jQuery Autocomplete](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-autocomplete-not-showing-for-ie8)

I had not even thought about the DOCTYPE being a problem until I read this link.

I was using this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

That was causing my problem.  I had a different test page with the code working on it and it was using this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

What I ended up going with for the time being is the new HTML5 DOCTYPE, which works.... at least for right now :)  Who knows what other code I may add that will give me trouble going forward.... or if I end up deploying to some users that may not have HTML5 capability.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using jQuery 1.6 and up. Older ones had a bug that stopped them from working in IE9